# Only showing data with 'true' or '1' in dropdown list, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a drop down list that uses a join to get the names of staff from a mysql `staff` table and display in my form, when the staff name is clicked and the form is submitted, the `ID` of the staff get stored in my main table. The problem is that all the staff members are showing, even if they their available status is "0" for false. Is there any way to only show the staff with an available status of "1?"
I have tried to use a where clause but it seemed to do nothing.

My controller:

```
   public function vehiclereport()
    {
        $startDate = request()->input('startDate', '2021-01-01');
        $endDate = request()->input('endDate', '2021-12-12');
        $energy = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
            ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')->where('available', 1)
            ->when(request()->input('smsstaff_key'), function ($query) {
                $query->where('smsstaff.smsstaff_key', request()->input('smsstaff_key'));
            })
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '>=', $startDate)
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '<=', $endDate)->orderBy('log_dt', 'desc')
            ->get();
        $cars = Vehicle::get();
        $staff = Staff::all();
        return view('admin.vehiclereport', compact('energy', 'cars', 'staff', 'startDate', 'endDate'));
    }
```

View:

```
<label>Pick a staff member</label>
                        <select name="smsstaff_key" id="smsstaff_key" required>
                            <option >----------------Select-----------------</option>
                            @foreach ($staff as $staffMember) 
                               <option value="{{$staffMember->smsstaff_key}}" {{request()->input('smsstaff_key') === $staffMember->smsstaff_key ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>{{$staffMember->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                       </select>
```

Comment: Why don't you also use a `where` like you do on "energy"?

Comment: Yes I did that on `  $staff = Staff::all()->where('available',1);` and I added an orderBy() but that doesn't seem to work, any ideas on that?

Comment: First of all don't use all and then filter with where. It will retrieve everything first and then filter in the application layer in memory. Use staff::query() - >where. Also check in the db if the values are actually 1